# After Route Change, run js script once

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to implement a system, where after the route changes, I would like to run my animation based javascript only once. What happens is that, right now if you switch between pages, and return back to about page. the scrips really slow down the website, which is what I am trying to avoid.

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $route) {

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() { 


  // Just need this to run once
  $('#about').particleground({
      dotColor: '#666',
      lineColor: '#666',
      lineWidth: .3,
      particleRadius: 3,
      parallaxMultiplier: 3
  });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `currentRoute.redirectTo` before running the animation inside $routeChangeSuccess`. It will prevent the animation from running multiple times.

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, currentRoute, previousRoute){
  if(!currentRoute.redirectTo) {
              $('#about').particleground({
                dotColor: '#666',
                lineColor: '#666',
                lineWidth: .3,
                particleRadius: 3,
                parallaxMultiplier: 3
             });
       }
});
```

The reason why it's executing twice is:

In your HTML:

```
<a href="#about">›&nbsp;&nbsp;About Me</a>
```

In the href, you have just `#about` but it must be `#/about`.

```
<a href="#/about">›&nbsp;&nbsp;About Me</a>
```

Comment: Still repeats.. you can see test page at: devncode.com/#/about

Comment: Updated my answer. In your menu link href you have `#about` it must be `#/about`

Comment: Updated the href values but it is still causing the same problem